# Why isn't my firebase config working?

Tags: firebase, react-native

I'm trying to modularize my code as best as I can. If sharing my App.js on github or something, I don't want to have to keep deleting the id's, I'd rather just include it on a separate file and just .gitignore it.

For some reason, my app is just really not liking the way I'm doing it and I'm having a tough time working around it. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

This is my App.js file:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import {
  apiKey,
  authDomain,
  databaseURL,
  storageBucket,
  messagingSenderId
} from './constants/Keys';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._navContext = initNavigationContext();
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    const config = {
     apiKey,
     authDomain,
     databaseURL,
     storageBucket,
     messagingSenderId
   };

    firebase.initializeApp(config);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={Store}>
        <NavigationProvider context={this._navContext}>
          <StackNavigation navigatorUID="root" id="root" initialRoute={Router.getRoute('auth')} />
        </NavigationProvider>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I've omitted the other import statements for here.

Here is my `Keys` file:

```
const apiKey = '//////';
const authDomain = '//////';
const databaseURL = '//////';
const storageBucket = '//////';
const messagingSenderId = '//////';


const facebookAppID = '//////';

export default {
  apiKey,
  authDomain,
  databaseURL,
  storageBucket,
  messagingSenderId,
  facebookAppID
};
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that you are trying to destructure the default export, and what ES6 modules do is use destructuring for named exports. If your imported values have all `undefined`, it is likely the case. You can do the following:

```
export const apiKey = '//////';
export const authDomain = '//////';
export const databaseURL = '//////';
export const storageBucket = '//////';
export const messagingSenderId = '//////';


export const facebookAppID = '//////';
```

And then it should work.